# AngularJS doesn't update img src when model changes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I use `ng-src` to load images. Value is loaded from some scope variable, like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{currentReceipt.image}}"/>
```

My issue is that when I run `delete $scope.currentReceipt`, it makes `ng-src` attribute empty but doesn't reflect it in `src` attribute. So as a result I keep seeing that image where I need empty placeholder.

How can I deal with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [empty ng-src doesn't update image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092687/empty-ng-src-doesnt-update-image)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour from the ngSrc and ngHref directives. These directives only support recognising new paths, but when path is not available, the directives will [exit silently](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.0.7/src/ng/directive/booleanAttrs.js#L306) (I see a pull request here.).

So a possible workaround could be to use ngShow along with the ngHref to hide the tag altogether when image variable is not available anymore:

```html
<img ng-href="{{currentReceipt.image}}" ng-show="currentReceipt.image" />
```

Comment: +1 for using `ng-show`, you may also want to consider removing the image from the DOM with `ng-switch` if you want it completely removed.

Comment: Thanks, seems like I have to workaround it the way you suggest. I have had a look inside Angular code managing ng-src directive and noticed that too, that it just exits, if no value given, not removing existing src value or anything like that. I have decided to use ng-class to manage cases like this. Thanks!

Comment: I guess the authors intentionally made the directive to just exit if value is undefined, because removing/clearing the src attribute makes the browser display the broken image thumbnail, which isn't really desired.

Answer (score 12):

call $scope.$apply() after delete $scope.currentReceipt.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works for me:

```
<img ng-src="{{currentReceipt.image}}" ng-show="currentReceipt.image != null" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually check for length and do

```
 <img ng-show="user.thumbnail.length > 1" class="img-circle thumb pull-left" ng-src="{{user.thumbnail}}" alt="{{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}}">
```