# empty ng-src doesn't update image

Tags: angularjs

I am using the **ng-src** directive in order to avoid the browser to request the image before Angular evaluate the expression.

`ng-src={{image}}` will update the *src* attribute of the image if the expression "image" change. 
I misunderstand why the *ng-src* directive doesn't update the path of the image if the expression ("myImage.png") become empty ("").

When the expression become empty, the *ng-src* attribute become empty but the *src* attribute still the last known *src*. So it doesn't update the image. Why the *src* attribute isn't updated (to an empty *src*) so that the image "disappear".

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eYk9je?p=preview)

Thanks

Comment: This depends on how you set the values. You need to share some code here.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The answer to this is in the **Angular** code. It's not a bug, it's just the behavior they decided they wanted. Starting on line 13895, you can see this directive code:

```
forEach(['src', 'srcset', 'href'], function(attrName) {
   var normalized = directiveNormalize('ng-' + attrName);
   ngAttributeAliasDirectives[normalized] = function() {
   return {
      priority: 99, // it needs to run after the attributes are interpolated
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
          attr.$observe(normalized, function(value) {

         if (!value)
             return;

         attr.$set(attrName, value);

         if (msie) element.prop(attrName, attr[attrName]);
       });
     }
    };
  };
});
```

The key is in:

`if (!value) return;`

So as you can see, if you change the **ng-src** expression to an empty string, this will never change the actual **src** value. You can get around this doing something MadScone suggested.

Comment: The question is more, why did they choose such a behavior. It leaves the image element in an inconsistant state. The image is shown while the model is empty.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what were their thought behind this decision. What I think is:

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what were their thoughts behind this decision. What I think is: As per [link](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html), **src** has to be a _non-empty URL potentially surrounded by space_ in order to be valid. But more important than that, as you can read here [link](http://gtmetrix.com/avoid-empty-src-or-href.html), an empty **src** can lead to multiple problems. Maybe this was what they were trying to prevent.

Comment: Ok, thank you for these links! I didn't know much about an empty src. Anyway @MadScone trick is a great workaround! It is tempting to add this trick in a custom directive (data-custom-src) :)

Comment: You can also use jQuery to set the image src directly. Not sure how big of an impact it'll have on the subsequent jQuery digest cycles.

Answer (score 40):

MadScone's suggestion is a cool idea, but it didn't work for me in all browsers. I ended up just showing the element only when the src isn't empty:

```
<img ng-show="theImage!==''" ng-src="{{theImage}}">
```

This seems like the safest option to me after reading through the thread that MadScone referenced ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775469/whats-the-valid-way-to-include-an-image-with-no-src)). As a number of people pointed out there, the accepted answer doesn't work in all browsers and has some other issues that could arise. Simply hiding the element avoids all that.

**Update:**
As enpenax pointed out in the comments, the `!==''` in the ng-show is totally unnecessary. Here's the cleaner version:

```
<img ng-show="theImage" ng-src="{{theImage}}">
```

Comment: <img ng-show="theImage" ng-src="{{theImage}}"> for me this does the trick already as ng-show evaluates to bool and an empty string AND null will turn out to be false.

Comment: I also came to the same conclusion that using the ng-show is the better work around to the problem. I actually use ng-if, but the concept of the solution is the same.

Comment: This is way late, but @enpenax has a great point. Empty string is falsy, so the !== was totally unnecessary. I'll update with that info.

Answer (score 27):

## Update (April 2015)

See developering's answer, apparently this method I suggested originally may not work in all browsers.

---

## Original (February 2014)

I'm not fully sure why that's happening, but here's a way of solving it anyway. Add this function to your controller:

```
$scope.getImage = function(src) {
  if (src !== "") {
    return src;  
  } else {
   return "//:0"; 
  }
};
```

The "blank" image will get a source of `//:0` which won't cause a missing image icon to appear (see the top answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775469/whats-the-valid-way-to-include-an-image-with-no-src)).

Then you can set your source using:

```
<img ng-src="{{getImage(superImage)}}" />
```

**EDIT:**

Actually, it would be easier to change your button click to this:

```
<button ng-click="superImage = '//:0'">Remove superImage</button>
```

Then there's no need for the function. Although I think the function method is better.

Comment: shorthand: `return src || "//:0";`

Comment: This is a cool idea and worked for me in some browsers, but not in everything. The main issue is that "//:0" doesn't actually work everywhere. I added another answer that will should across the board.

Comment: @developering Fair enough. I've updated my answer for any unsuspecting people in future who may not read the all the answers or might miss your comment.

Answer (score 9):

Another short way of solving it:
`<img ng-src="{{image?image:' '}}" />`

Answer (score 4):

fix it by set value = " ";
with whitespace.

I also add the following css to make sure it's not displayed.

```
img[src="_"]
    display none !important
```

the real reason has been discussed here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1218

Answer (score 1):

ng-hide and ng-show can help you solve it

```html
<img ng-src="{{Image}}" ng-hide="Image == null" ng-show="Image != null" ng-click="ChooseImage()" width="100%"  />
```

$scope.Image = null;

or

```html
<img ng-src="{{Image}}" ng-hide="Image === ''" ng-show="Image !== ''" ng-click="ChooseImage()" width="100%"  />
```

$scope.Image = '';

Answer (score 0):

`<img data-ng-src="{{image || 'http://www.1x1px.me/FFFFFF-0.png'}}" data-ng-model="image">`

You can choose any 1x1px image that suitable to your website and replace http://www.1x1px.me/FFFFFF-0.png of your own. For my website I use available image on http://www.1x1px.me.

P/S: No need to worry about the original src attribute of img tag because it's not affected to image model

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround to empty `ng-src` can be found [here.](https://makandracards.com/makandra/29415-resolving-angular-not-updating-an-image-src-when-ng-src-is-empty)

```
<img ng-src="{{image || '//:0' }}" />
```

Detailed explanation to use `//:0` can be found [from this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5775621/4921959)

To summarize:

> It adopts the current protocol, omits the hostname and sets the port to zero, which is invalid and should be killed by the network layer.

Also instead of emptying `ng-src`, if you have a default image source then you can simply set the `ng-src` to that default src when `ng-src` have to be empty.

Answer (score -3):

```
 <img src="{{superImage}}" />
```

This works as expected
Edit:

Other work arround,may be you could have used and empty string.

```
ng-click="superImage = ' '
```

to make it empty. It does not trigger 404

Comment: using the src attribute will trigger a request before Angular evaluate the expression superImage which will result in a 404 not found.